# Can't reach custom C# forms application remotely

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, service, windows

I'm working in Windows Server 2008.

I have a very basic C# forms application (not a service) that is listening on a port, say 56112.  When using telnet I can connect from the localhost and send and receive data.  For some reason I cannot remotely connect to the application.  I know I have a connection because I can telnet to 23 on the remotely fine.

I've opened this port on the firewall, created rules in/out in advanced firewall, disabled the firewall completely, and more.

Any suggestions would be great!

This is the telnet output:

```
Microsoft Telnet> open server.cc 56112
Connecting server.cc...Could not open connection to the host, on port
56112: Connect failed
```

The nmap output indicates that the port isn't even open?!  I've created the rules for in on Windows Firewall (+ advanced firewall) and still cannot see those changes remotely.

```
Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2010-04-17 14:04 Pacific Daylight Time
Nmap scan report for 192.168.56.101
Host is up (0.0017s latency).
Not shown: 89 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
80/tcp    open  http
135/tcp   open  msrpc
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
5357/tcp  open  unknown
49152/tcp open  unknown
49153/tcp open  unknown
49154/tcp open  unknown
49155/tcp open  unknown
49156/tcp open  unknown
49157/tcp open  unknown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a networking whiz so tell me if this is elementary:

Based off the patterns I saw from the output of netstat -an I changed
`serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);`
To
`serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), port);`

Also used nmap which was very helpful, but didn't report the port opened while I was using localhost's IP as the server.  Once I made the host change I noticed that nmap also reported the port as opened, pretty strange in my opinion.

Comment: Makes sense. If you bind to a specific IP address the application will only answer to that IP. If you bind to 0.0.0.0 you actually bind to all local addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Time to drag out the network debugging tools:

- What does [nmap](http://nmap.org/download.html) say if you probe the
  port from the remote system?
- What
  does the interaction look like if you
  capture the data using [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) when
  you try to connect? Do you get an RST?

Comment: nmap indicated that the port isn't even open, even though I have modified the firewall.